# JSch: How to configure diffie-hellman-group14-sha256?

Tags: sftp, jsch, diffie-hellman

I am trying to connect to a ssh server with diffie-hellman-group14-sha256@ssh.com, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 algorithm.

But my JSch client always encrypts with diffie-hellman-group14-sha1.

What can I do to setup the sha256 algorithm?

The problem occurs on our test environment only. The settings there are same as prod environments. Just OpenSSH version differs - it is newer on test.

Java version: 1.8.0_151

Server logs: "The JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy File was found"

Available in server lib: jce_policy-8/US_export_policy.jar, jce_policy-8/local_policy.jar

**My code looks like:**

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch(); 
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp c = null;

        //Now connect and SFTP to the SFTP Server
        try {
            //Create a session sending through our username and password
            session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);    
            session.setPassword(ftpPassword);

            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            //
            //Open the SFTP channel
            //
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            c = (ChannelSftp)channel;
            status = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            status = "Unable to connect to FTP server. "+e.toString();
        }
```

**Log out is:**

```
INFO: Connecting to X.X.X.X port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-6.4.13.36 SSH Tectia Server
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
**INFO**:   CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
        CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
**INFO: kex: server**: diffie-hellman-group14-sha256@ssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-sha256@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc,crypticore128@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc,crypticore128@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-sha256-2@ssh.com,hmac-sha224@ssh.com,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com,crypticore-mac@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-sha256-2@ssh.com,hmac-sha224@ssh.com,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com,crypticore-mac@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
**INFO: kex: client**: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
INFO: Permanently added '160.58.9.72' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
```

I've tried to set the SHA256 algorithm by putting the same algorithms in the same order as the server logs without success:

```
config.put("kex", "diffie-hellman-group14-sha256@ssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1");
```

**Log when algorithm order is the same**

```
INFO: Connecting to X.X.X.X port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-6.4.13.36 SSH Tectia Server
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group14-sha256@ssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-sha256@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc,crypticore128@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc,crypticore128@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-sha256-2@ssh.com,hmac-sha224@ssh.com,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com,crypticore-mac@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-sha256-2@ssh.com,hmac-sha224@ssh.com,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com,crypticore-mac@ssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib
INFO: kex: server:   
INFO: kex: server:   
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client:   
INFO: kex: client:   
INFO: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
INFO: Permanently added 'X.X.X.X' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
INFO: Disconnecting from X.X.X.X port 22
INFO: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I did as you mentioned and put the algorithms in server's order again. I added it to the post above. But I don't receive any additionally information from it. The Jsch version is still 1.53. Although I added 1.55. But that's a problem of our server set up and my rights to install other versions. Is it absolutely necessary for analysis? On other systems we are using 1.53 too and don't have any problems.

Comment: I tried another time with algorithms in the same order on server and client. I got some more logs - see above (Log when algorithms are in same order) . But still I don't get sufficient information and don't have any idea how to proceed. Can anyone help?